# How to get string value from a service activity?

Tags: string, android-activity, get

My MainACtivity.java calls a service activity (GCM.java) for registering to GCM and sending registration id to server.

I want to retrieve the registration id in my MainActivity to use it. How can this be done?

I tried using Intents but that makes me go back my MainActivity and i dont want that.

Thanks

Comment: you want to send the registrationId obtained in Service back to your activity ?

Comment: Please see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909377/how-to-send-data-from-service-to-activity

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I will try this as well

However I searched and figured out it was easier done by storing it in sharedPreference and retrieving it in MainActivity

Comment: actually this is the proper way of communication not the way with shared preference.